# How to return output as enum in powershell v3 ?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using following function to find out whether the release is Major ,Patch or Invalid.

```
Function Compare-Version {

    [cmdletBinding()]
    Param (

        [version] $old,
        [Version] $New

    )

        If ( $New -le $Old  ) { return "Invalid" }
        ElseIf ( $new.Major -eq $Old.Major -And $New.Minor -gt $Old.Minor ) { return "Patch" }
        ElseIf ($new -gt $old) { return "Major" }

}

$TypeOfRelease = Compare-Version -Old "245.1" -New "246.1"

If ($TypeOfRelease -eq "Invalid" ) { "No operation"}
ElseIf ($TypeOfRelease -eq "Major") {"Change guid to support migration"}
Elseif ($TypeOfRelease -eq "Point") {"Just change the version don't upgrade GUID")
```

I hope enum can be of right choice rather than string. How to send enum as output result and compare it in powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell v5 you will be able to declare enums directly e.g.:

```
enum VersionCompare { Invalid; Major; Patch }
```

In v3 you will need to use Add-Type e.g.:

```
PS> Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'public enum VersionCompare { Invalid, Major, Patch }'
PS> [VersionCompare]::Invalid
Invalid
```